# Joomla error with content deletions after upgraded php 7.4

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, php-7

I just upgraded php 5.6 to 7.4 in my server where Joomla 3.x is running.

After I upgraded php version to the 7.4 I got problem. I can't delete any content (user, article, pages) as admin, I got this error:

> Too few arguments to function plgContentFormLogger::onContentBeforeDelete(), 2 passed in /home/website/libraries/joomla/event/event.php on line 70 and exactly 3 expected

Problem is still there even if I downgrade php version to 7.3, 7.2 and even 7.1. Can someone please help me, because I can't figured this out?

Code:

```
public function update(&$args)
{
    // First let's get the event from the argument array.  Next we will unset the
    // event argument as it has no bearing on the method to handle the event.
    $event = $args['event'];
    unset($args['event']);

    /*
     * If the method to handle an event exists, call it and return its return
     * value.  If it does not exist, return null.
     */

    if (method_exists($this, $event))
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $event), $args); // line 70
    }
}
```

Content deleting problem solved when I edit this line like this:

```
return call_user_func_array(array($this, $event), $args, 0);
```

but after that I can't login any user / user roles.

Problem solved for now.

In this function I removed `$isNew`

```
public function onContentBeforeDelete($context, $table, $isNew) {
$this->_log('onContentBeforeDelete', $context);
}
```

Comment: The upgrade between major versions of PHP can introduce backward incompatible changes. Have you checked that your plugins are compatible with PHP7? Beyond that, the message is clear enough - the plugin code is expecting three arguments and it's only getting two. If it's your code that's calling it you'll need to work out what the extra parameter should be and provide it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my first post. Now it seems working correctly. No warnings or errors. Content deletion works.

Answer (score 1):

Can't yet comment:

Looking at the php documentation the method call_user_func_array doesn't have three arguments.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func-array.php

I would assume that the first array which should have the class ($this) and the callable method name (value in $event) are not valid.

Did you contact the developer of your plugin? He should provide you a newer version, which is PHP 7 compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my first post with the solution. Need more testing tho, but seems like it works now.